# Questionmark in function name

Tags: haskell

I was just taking a look into clojure and found the following line of code on an example page

```
(filter even? [1 2 3])
```

While this is fairly standard code i am amazed by the fact, that they use a '?' to make the predicate easier to read.

Is it also possible to get haskell to accept this as a function name?
So far i found https://wiki.haskell.org/Unicode-symbols which unfortunately does not contain '?'.

Comment: Yeah we also have such a thing in the Elixir community (can't say we invented it, though :p). It's so convenient! There's also the whole `function!` versus `function`, where the former raises an exception when failing wheras the other returns a `{:ok, result}` or `{:error, error}` (which is easily done with Either.

Comment: @Uniaika interesting. I don't think scala has it though.

Comment: This is standard closure naming policy afaik: http://toblux.com/2014/05/28/idiomatic-function-names-in-clojure/ An exclamation is used for non-pure functions, etc.

Comment: Ruby uses it as well (+ `!` for other cases).

Comment: Feel free to make a proposal to haskell-prime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this.

Gross hack: `?` is not a valid identifier character, but `ʔ` is.

Don't use the following.

```
evenʔ :: Num a => a -> Bool
evenʔ 0 = True
evenʔ 1 = False
evenʔ n = evenʔ (n - 2)
```

(`ʔ`, of course, is U+0294 LATIN LETTER GLOTTAL STOP, which, appearances aside, is completely unrelated to U+003F QUESTION MARK.)

Did I mention you shouldn't do this?

Comment: Almost should count as a solution. But i think people will kill me if i do this in my code.

Answer (score 3):

From the Haskell 2010 Language Report (https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4):

> varid →   (small {small | large | digit | ' })⟨reservedid⟩

and

> Underscore, “_”, is treated as a lowercase letter, and can occur wherever a lowercase letter can. However, “_” all by itself is a reserved identifier, used as wild card in patterns.

In other words, identifiers must start with a lowercase letter or `_`, and can only contain lowercase letters, `_`'s, uppercase letters, digits and `'`s.

I'm not aware of any language extension that would allow this. Also it would force users of such a module to enable the extension as well so I'm not convinced it is a good idea. The convention in Haskell code is to call a function like this `isEven` which is what the users of your code will expect anyway. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: Thats what i thought. So basically the question would be, if there exists an extension to do this - or it could be written in theory (to much for such a small case).

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell we can't use `?` inside variable names, except when using a particular extension, [Implicit Parameters](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=implicit#ghc-flag--XImplicitParams) which however changes the scoping rules of the variable.

With that extension, variable names can have a *leading* question mark, as in `?foo`. However, this marks `foo` as an implicit argument. For example:

```hs
f :: (?x :: Int) => Int -> Int
f y = ?x + y   -- x is in scope here

main :: IO ()
main = do
   let ?x :: Int
       ?x = 23
   print (f 10)   -- ?x is also passed, implicitly
```

Essentially, this makes `?x` to have dynamic instead of static/lexical scoping.

It is a mostly unused extension, in practice. (I still find it nice to have it, though.)

This is surely *not* what you want, but perhaps worth mentioning. If you ever see names with a leading `?` in Haskell, know that they are quite special.

Comment: Interesting. This is not a feature i want, but it means, that is is possible to add characters to the list of available ones for function names.

Comment: The documentation says "An implicit parameter occurs in an expression using the special form ?x, where x is any valid identifier (e.g. ord ?x is a valid expression)". So it seems `?` is not considered to be part of the name, strictly speaking.

Comment: @Xlaech Well, some extensions do extend the syntax, but this is not something that can be freely controlled by the programmer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Ah, interesting. I never realized that, since from the point of view of the syntax there's not much difference.